# C++: While loop won't terminate as NULL, am I missing something?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, linked-list, terminate

It seems that I can't figure out why the while loop wont terminate.

It should be while(null) essentially.

I can't figure it out.

All help would be appreciated :D

I dont know what could possibly be stopping the while loop at all?  It says that the first entry gets stored, and the entry for next is at 0x0000000000 and ??? name and ??? ??? coords so it is in fact NULL.  I tried adding in the constructor next = 0; instead of next = NULL and it still did not work.

Thanks guys.

Anthony

```
EDIT:  Value of nodePtr = 00000000 if next = 0 in the constructor
       Value of nodePtr = 00899FE0 if next = NULL in the constructor
if adding a cout << nodePtr->next; before the while.
```

http://pastebin.com/7usYdfHB -- Full program for reference.

EDIT2: 
[image: http://i.imgur.com/fKCoSjV.png]
Is the popup when I go to enter the 2nd entry.

```
void LinkedList::appendNode(string name, double x, double y)
{
        ListNode* newNode; // To point to new node
        ListNode* nodePtr; // To traverse List

        // allocate new node
        newNode = new ListNode(name, x, y);

        // If no head, head is the newNode
        // else traverse the list to find the end and append newNode
        if (!head)
        {
                head = newNode;
                cout << "Record inserted successfully.\n" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
                nodePtr = head;

                //traverse the list loop
                while (nodePtr->next) //VS 2012 locks up here <-----
                {

                        //Checks for duplicate entry by name
                        if (nodePtr->cityName == name)
                        {
                                cout << "No need to insert again, as this record exists in the existing data set.\n" << endl;
                                return;
                        }
                        //traverse the list
                        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
                }
                // checks 2nd entry, as while loop wont run for a 2nd entry.
                if (nodePtr->cityName == name)                  {
                        {
                                cout << "No need to insert again, as this record exists in the existing data set.\n" << endl;
                                return;
                        }
                }
                // if next is NULL add newNode
                else if (!nodePtr->next)
                {
                        nodePtr->next = newNode;
                        cout << "Record inserted successfully.\n" << endl;
                }
        }
```

Comment: Do you initialize next to NULL in your constructor for ListNode?

Comment: Post the constructor. Actually, post two of them: one of `LinkedList` and another of `ListNode`.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/7usYdfHB

Comment: Hint: When the `name` already is in the list, you are leaking memory, as the `newNode` you have allocated is never deleted!

Comment: I enter the first entry, and it goes in fine.  I enter the 2nd one and it won't pass the while loop, i'm not sure if a memory leak is the issue.

Comment: You are right. newNode should only be allocated when inserting it is needed. Besides, it could be usefull to keep track of the tail of you list too, so your loop goes from tail to head.

Comment: After reading your program, you really should keep track of the tail as all of your loops start from head, not caring about nodes before it.

Comment: @discobeat he does not want duplicate city names in the list so he needs to traverse the list every time when appending.

Comment: Concerning the problem you describe, your code looks fine and shouldn't behave that way. If I compile it with gcc, it works without problems. Create a breakpoint in the `while` loop and debug your program to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Aside from the obvious memory leak when an attempt to insert an already existing name is made, your code looks and works fine. It works fine when either `0` or `NULL` is used. It makes no difference. So, what does the calling code look like?

Comment: @claptrap Ok head is the start of the list. My bad. It is generally a good habit to keep track of both side of the list.

Comment: @discobeat yep I agree fully

Comment: i find the { } matching seems a bit off, especially after the second `if (nodePtr->cityName == name)`

Comment: Probably a formatting error. Just need to find a new ide and compiler I think.  Prolly gonna go back to NetBeans for c++ just need to reinstall cygwin or something similar.  Cygwin seems so bulky though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the obvious memory leak when an attempt to insert an already existing name is made, your code seems to work fine. It works fine when either `0` or `NULL` is used to initialize the pointers. It makes no difference.

(One wild guess I can make is that in your actual calling code (which you do not show), you somehow managed to pass your `LinkedList` around *by value*. Since your `LinkedList` does not satisfy the Rule of Three, the integrity of the list got violated, which lead to undefined consequences you observed.)

BTW, by using an extra level of indirection you can simplify your heavily branched `appendNode` function into a significantly more compact and almost branchless one

```
void LinkedList::appendNode(string name, double x, double y)
{
        ListNode** pnodePtr;

        for (pnodePtr = &head; *pnodePtr != NULL; pnodePtr = &(*pnodePtr)->next)
                if ((*pnodePtr)->cityName == name)
                        break;

        if (*pnodePtr == NULL)
        {
                  *pnodePtr = new ListNode(name, x, y);
                  cout << "Record inserted successfully.\n" << endl;
        }
        else
                  cout << "No need to insert again, as this record exists in the existing data set.\n" << endl;
}
```

(I also eliminated the leak.) Specifically, this technique allows one to avoid writing a dedicated branch for processing the head node.

**Also** (referring to the full version of the code), in your functions from "delete by coordinate" group you for some reason check *both* `x` and `y` coordinates of the head node, but only *one* coordinate of the other nodes down the list. Why? This is rather weird and does not seem to make much sense. Meanwhile, functions from "search by coordinate" group do not have this issue - they process all nodes consistently.

**Also**, your `displayList` function suffers from a stray `return` at the very beginning, which is why it never prints anything. You need to add a pair of `{}` to properly group your statements.

Comment: I can show the other file used to start the call tomorrow morning.  Appreciate the help.  It actually runs through the first set of data though which is weird. Maybe it's just the compiler for VS2012.

Comment: @user2565679: I ran your code and entered a number of entries into the list without any issues. Your code prints the list `head` value during each insertion (except for the first one), but otherwise it works as expected. And no, it is more than unlikely to be a problem with the compiler.

Comment: Why is vs12 giving me an issue then? :(

Comment: @user2565679: Well, I was running your code in Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2013 without any issues. If you getting problems from this code, you need to debug it step by step and figure out when and where they occur for the first time. The only guess I can make at this point is that there's something else you are not showing us.

Comment: That is all that is implemented at this point, except 
int main()
{
Output();
return 0;
}

Also posted a picture of where it stops,  It stops at the while(nodePtr->next) line,

Comment: @user2565679: That's exactly how I ran your code: `int main() { Output(); return 0; }`. So, again, what exactly is the problem? You said you are getting an infinite cycle on the insertion. Is that still the case? And if so, what is the minimal input that leads to that situation?

Comment: I do B then 1.  Input a city and x/y.  Stores successfully, can be searched, and such.

Then I do B then 1, Input city, and x/y as soon as I hit enter after y, it locks up and throws me to line while(nodePtr->next)

Comment: Upon further investigation, there was a breakpoint created last night automatically from VS12, maybe I just needed to restart my PC. Hmm, so to take care of the "memory leak" in my code, could I just add "delete newNode" before the return and that fix the extra memory floating around.

Comment: @user2565679: A much better idea would be not to create the new node until you are sure you need it. Do the search first. And only when you are already sure the node does not exist, create it and attach it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your problem but could not. I reverse engineered your ListNode and LinkedList classes. The code below works, maybe that will help you sort out your issue. I refactored it a little to simplify it (going further you should consider keeping track of the end of the list as this will help with other operations that your list will need). Be sure to implement a destructor for your LinkedList class to clean up the nodes.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct ListNode
{
    string cityName;
    double m_x, m_y;
    ListNode* next;

    ListNode(string name, double x, double y) : cityName(name), m_x(x), m_y(y), next(nullptr)
    {}
};

class LinkedList
{
    ListNode* head;
public:
    LinkedList() : head(nullptr)
    {
    }
    ~LinkedList()
    {
    }
    void LinkedList::appendNode(string name, double x, double y)
    {
        ListNode* newNode; // To point to new node

        // allocate new node
        newNode = new ListNode(name, x, y);

        // If no head, head is the newNode
        // else traverse the list to find the end and append newNode
        if (!head)
        {
            head = newNode;
            cout << "Record inserted successfully.\n" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            ListNode *nodePtr = head;
            ListNode *prevNode = nullptr;

            //traverse the list loop
            while (nodePtr)
            {

                //Checks for duplicate entry by name
                if (nodePtr->cityName == name)
                {
                    cout << "No need to insert again, as this record exists in the existing data set.\n" << endl;
                    return;
                }
                //traverse the list
                prevNode = nodePtr;
                nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
            }
            // if next is NULL add newNode
            if (prevNode)
            {
                prevNode->next = newNode;
                cout << "Record inserted successfully.\n" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    LinkedList list;

    list.appendNode("New York", 1.0, 2.0);
    list.appendNode("Boston", 1.5, 2.5);
    list.appendNode("Miami", 1.7, 2.7);
    list.appendNode("Miami", 1.7, 2.7);
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the help, friend.  Maybe my compiler for VS2012 isnt liking it.  I usually use Netbeans with cygwin, but have since reformatted my pc.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/1NDph751  here is the code that calls it, i'm assuming its a compiler thing, though.